# AWS Lambda checking multiple file exist condition - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, race-condition, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which triggers when an object is uploaded to an S3 bucket - I want to perform an action once two specific items are uploaded. How can I do this without worrying about performing the action twice if both files are uploaded at the same time and the Lambda function is triggered twice?

For example: there are two types of files .X and .Y, each file pair will have the same name - 123.X and 123.Y, or 124.X and 124.Y. Lets say that I want to concatenate these files once they both exist. You could do something like the following pseudocode:

```
lambda_handler(event):
    key = event[...]['key']
    unique_id = key.split('.')[0]
    files = get_files_with_unique_id_from_bucket(unique_id)
    if files['.X'] and files['.Y']:
        concatenate(files['.X'], files['.Y'])
```

Sorry for the lazy pseudocode...

How would I do this without worrying about the triggers happening at the same time and both meeting the condition to concatenate? For the purposes of this question, the concatenation happening twice would be bad.

Comment: What would be the problem with triggering the handler and not having it do the concatenation? You've already got a check to see if both files exist. And as for avoiding concatenating twice, consider deleting one of the files after concatenation so that prevents the re-concat even if it's triggered after. Or create a concatenated '.Z' file and check for its existence prior to concat'ing X and Y; like `if files['.X'] and files['.Y'] and not files['.Z']:`

Comment: @aneroid, I need to keep the .X and .Y files. The concatenation was just an example. In reality I'm running some third party software over both of them to produce some metrics. I don't want that to happen twice. The 'concatenation' doesn't necessarily have to be performed by the initial lambda handler - but in the above example, both invocations of the Lambda function will concatenate the files if they are triggered at the same time.

Comment: as for creating a new file and checking for it's existence. This won't necessarily work if they are both triggered at the same time. As they might both check if the new file exists at the same time and see that it does not - then both concatenate. If the concatenation takes some time, for example.

Comment: Understood, was about to point out the same problem with my suggestion (race condition wrt creating/checking for Z). Will leave the previous comment in for future readers' info.

Comment: Possible solution: 2 Lambda functions.  First checks for X and Y, and if they both exist, creates a new file in another bucket whose name is unique for the given (X,Y).  If multiple Lambda function invocations do this, you still get only one creation event in S3.  Second Lambda function watches this other bucket.

Comment: Good idea. A friend gave me a similar idea but with DynamoDB entries. Will have to check if you get charged for those s3 puts. It certainly increases the cost on Lambda triggers.